# Objective C. Exiting modal and pushing to a new controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Okay, so here's the issue. From a view controller there's a modal that pops up. I need to be able to exit out of the modal and link to a specific view controller in ANOTHER storyboard. So there are two storyboards in this app. The code below exits out of the view controller no problem. But it does not solve my problem of linking to the other storyboards view controller(s).

```
- (IBAction)cancelFlow:(id)sender {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dismissMyModal" object:nil];
}
```

-- Folder1 --

- MyFirstStoryboard.storyboard

  - myModal.h/m

-- Folder2 --

- MySecondStoryboard.storyboard

  - someViewController.h/m **<----- I NEED TO GET HERE FROM myModal.h/m**

So I believe the steps are..

1. Close modal
2. After close, link to other storyboard
3. Find and push to viewController

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of the navigation programmatically. Use presentViewController:animated:completion: after your modal has dismissed. The controller you present can be pulled from a storyboard with a given id:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard2" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyController"];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```